# Unable Trim value of a textBox using ngModel and directive

Tags: .net, angular, typescript, .net-core, angularjs-directive

**I am trying to trim a text input but it is duplicating the value** [image]

**I am new to angular can you please help me out finding the solution**
[StackBlitz Code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-igw8xh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.directice.ts,src%2Fapp%2FMyModel.ts)

Comment: Post your code as snippet instead of image. And try to add some explanation on what you try to achieve. Input element allowed for pasting number?

Comment: Can you please provide a [mre]? See [ask] for further guidance. Would it be possible for you to provide a [Stack Snippet](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/11107541)? Note: Stack Snippets are preferred over links to external repros for reasons explained in [ask].

Answer (score 0):

[`preventDefault()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp) Usage:

> The preventDefault() method cancels the event if it is cancelable, meaning that the default action that belongs to the event will not occur.

The problem was here, that you are trying to stop the pasting behavior.

```
if (!Number(event)) {
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

**Scenarios:**

**Scenario 1: Pasted value is not a number**

- It will block the pasting behavior.

**Scenario 2: Pasted value is a number**

- From the above code, it will not block the pasting behavior.
- And next you are assigning the value to the `<input>` element.
- Thus you will see the number will be duplicated.

---

I believe what you try to achieve:

1. Blocking the default pasting behavior.
2. Only allow the number to be pasted. When the value is not a number, it will exit the function.

```
if (!Number(event)) return;
```

The complete code of the "paste" listener should be as below:

```
@HostListener('paste', ['$event']) onPaste(e: ClipboardEvent) {
  e.preventDefault();

  let event = e.clipboardData.getData('text');

  let reg = new RegExp(/\s/g);
  //allow paste only number values
  if (!Number(event)) return;

  if (reg.test(event)) {
    console.log('Dir "' + event + '"');

    this.eleRef.nativeElement.value = event.trim();
  }
}
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b5ugqk?file=src/app/app.directice.ts)